# Laravel 5.7, do something before user logout

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to set the current user `type` field to something else before logout but the problem is, I don't know which controller or which method I should put this code at. Btw, I don't have AuthController in Laravel 5.7.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->type = "something";
$user->save;
```

Comment: Might be helpful for you https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Comment: I dont think this help me solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use EventSubscriber for it. 
Please take a look on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#event-subscribers).
Inside handle method you will be able to get user object like:

```
public function hanlde($event) 
{
    $user = $event->user;
    // You will be able to change user here
}
```

Other method:
If you look on LoginController, you will see that it uses trait named      "AuthenticatesUsers" (Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers).
And this trait has method named "logout"

```
    /**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

You can just copy/paste it in LoginController and rewrite it. 
PS: But I prefer the 1st option. But it's up to you. 
Hope it will help.

Comment: any other alternative besides this method?

Comment: @LearnProgramming I've added 2nd option in answer. Seems it's what you need.

Comment: oh nice, this is what i wanted